# Signature and Environment in Type Theory

Tags: logic, type-theory

*Signature* and *Environment* are both related to the description of constants. I feel confused about the two notions in type theory. Could anyone explain their main difference? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functionally, environment (or contexts) and signatures behave quite similarly, and in some settings you can emulate signatures using environments to place the axioms as variables in the context. However, they should be thought of differently.

An *environment* or *context* is typically a list of typed variables, e.g. $x_1 : A_1, \ldots, x_n : A_n$. Terms in this environment may project out the variables, e.g. $x_1 : A_1, x_2 : A_2 \vdash \langle x_2, x_1 \rangle : A_2 \times A_1$. The environment may differ during the course of a derivation, for instance if binding operators, like $\lambda$-abstractions, are used. In a certain sense, environments are a notion internal to the type theory.

A *signature* in type theory is a set of constants and function symbols (and potentially base types) that are given as axioms for the type theory (the exact form will differ depending on the treatment). These axioms may be used throughout a derivation, just like ordinary rules. However, the signature is fixed for a type theory: the signature may not change over the course of a derivation, unlike an environment. You can think of the type theory as being parameterised by the signature. Therefore, signatures are in some sense an external notion.

If the type theory in question has function types, we can represent function symbols from a signature as variables (of function types) in an environment, but this will only behave the same way as a signature if we do not bind those variables. Another way of thinking about it is that variables in an environment are *local* (and hence may not be available everywhere), whereas constants in a signature are *global* (and may be used at any point in a derivation).

Comment: Hi @varkor, thanks for the answer. If we take *environment*  as a synonym of *context*, then I can clearly see the difference between *environment* and *signature*. But in  the textbook *Type Theory and Formal Proof* by Nederpelt and Geuvers, they seem to treat *environment* and *context* as different notions. They define the notion of *environment* as "a finite (empty or non-empty) list of definitions". I don't know exactly how it differs from *signature* and *context*.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the notion of "environment" in Nederpelt–Geuvers is exactly what others would call a "signature", that is: a list of function symbols. (Constants can be described using Nederpelt–Geuvers's "(descriptive) definitions" in empty contexts.) They explicitly carry around this signature using the syntax $\Delta; \Gamma$, though in other treatments this parameterisation over the signature $\Delta$ will often be implicit.

Comment: Thanks! I have the same feeling. That's why I feel confused about this.

Comment: It's fairly common for different terminology to be used by different authors in mathematics and computer science. Perhaps the authors simply felt "signature" was an obfuscating term, to those unfamiliar with that term.